# drawLayer:inContext is not called

Tags: iphone, core-animation, core-graphics

I have my very own minimal view class with this:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    NSLog(@"awakeFromNib!");
    [self.layer setDelegate:self];
    [self.layer setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 250, 250)];
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    self.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    NSLog(@"drawing!");
}
```

drawLayer:inContext never get called, although I can see the layer as red, rounded corner rectangle. What am I missing?

EDIT: from Apple docs

> You can draw content for your layer,
>   or better encapsulate setting the
>   layer’s content image by creating a
>   delegate class that implements one of
>   the following methods: displayLayer:
>   or drawLayer:inContext:.
>
> Implementing a delegate method to draw
>   the content does not automatically
>   cause the layer to draw using that
>   implementation. Instead, you must
>   explicitly tell a layer instance to
>   re-cache the content, either by
>   sending it a setNeedsDisplay or
>   setNeedsDisplayInRect: message, or by
>   setting its needsDisplayOnBoundsChange
>   property to YES.

Also

> **drawLayer:inContext:**
>
> If defined, called by the default implementation
>   of drawInContext:.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should never change the delegate of layer of a UIView. From documentation of UIView layer property:

> Warning: Since the view is the layer’s
>   delegate, you should never set the
>   view as a delegate of another CALayer
>   object. Additionally, you should never
>   change the delegate of this layer.

If you want to do custom drawing in a view simply override the drawRect: method.

If you do want to use layers you need to create your own:

```
UIView *myView = ...
CALayer *myLayer = [CALayer layer];
myLayer.delegate = self;
[myView.layer addSublayer:myLayer];
```

In both cases you need to call setNeedsDisplay on the view in the first case and on your custom layer in the second. You never call drawRect: or drawLayer:inContext: directly, they are called automatically when you call setNeedsDisplay.

Answer (score 2):

Use

`[self.layer setNeedsDisplay];`

instead of

`[self setNeedsDisplay];`

---

It is the `view.layer`, not the `view`